# Implementing interface to a abstract class Java

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class

I was testing a program in which i was trying to implement a interface on abstract class . as given below

```
 interface Inf{
    void display();
}

abstract class InfTst implements Inf{

}

class InterfaceTest extends InfTst{
    void display(){
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

but it is shows error

> error: display() in InterfaceTest cannot implement display() in Inf
>           void display(){

what is this error means and how resolve it, please help me.

Comment: is there more to the error message?

Comment: if you use IDE you already see that it gives you the answer  `'display()' in InterfaceTest  clashes with 'display()' in Inf; attempting to assign weaker access privileged ('package-private'); was 'public'`

Comment: What might cause your confusion: When declaring an interface, all the method-stubs are automatically `public` even if you omit the keyword. So implementations have to be `public` explicitly. Without any keyword, the default visibility is applied - which is less than `public`.

Answer (score 4):

When you omit access modifier on an interface it defaults to public, but on concrete classes it defaults to package-private.

Change your method signature to below in concrete class `InterfaceTest`

```
public void display(){..}
```

Comment: the full error message probably mentioned something about reduced visibility.

Answer (score 0):

**In concrete classes by default package is private. A concrete method means, the method have complete definition**  so must be your method modifier are always public.

```
   package domain;
    interface Inf {
      void display();
     }
    abstract class InfTst implements Inf {
    }

 class InterfaceTest extends InfTst {
    public void display() {
    System.out.println("Hello");
}
}

 public class StackOverFlow extends InterfaceTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    StackOverFlow sof = new StackOverFlow();
    sof.display();

}
}
```

> output : - Hello